# Get refferer in php and set it as session

Tags: php, session, referrer

I'm trying to get the HTTP referrer if exist, set it as session and echo something if the ref is ....

So I have this to get the ref and set as session (before HMTL)

```
<?php 

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['ref'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
?>
```

And I call it

```
<?php

if (strpos($_SESSION['ref'], 'pinterest') == !FALSE) {
    echo 'Follow me on pinterest';
}
?>
```

If I navigate to pinterest and click a link to my site it works, but when I visit another internal page without quitting, the echo doesn't output nothing

I'm a newbie so If someone has a better code please post it here

Comment: do you call `session_start();` before calling `strpos($_SESSION['ref'], 'pinterest')`?

Comment: so when you visit another internal page your `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not empty and rewrite your `$_SESSION['ref']`. Assuming, that this code runs on every page:)

Comment: I don't get it @UshakovNik

Comment: If you put the code on a landing page like "yoursite.com/cool-article" then the referer is set to whatever the client came from. Now the visitor goes on with the second page of the article "yoursite.com/cool-article/2" then the referer gets overriden because its from "yoursite.com/cool-article"

Comment: just try `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` after `if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {`. I think you will see what is happening

Comment: Ok I see @UshakovNik. How can I fix that. I took those pieces of code everywhere on the web and tried to combine them togheter

Comment: well, if you want to ignore internal pages you can add some conditions, based on comparison of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` with your domain ([parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)). Anyway it depends on what you want

Comment: I want to get the referrer and keep it as variable until the user leave my site :) please @UshakovNik